# When to use a form vs surveys

Tags: reactjs, architecture, react-final-form, surveyjs

When does one choose to build your own form in ReactJS with form hooks, final form, formik vs using something like SurveyJS? Is doing your own form getting a little dated?

Answer (score 3):

SurveyJS is a library, which provides many advanced features that would otherwise take a significant amount of development work to reproduce:

- Multi-page forms
- Conditional display logic
- Question and page branching logic
- Localization and multi-lingual support
- Calculated fields
- Complex field types, such as matrix questions and dynamic panels
- Dynamic form definitions, based on JSON specifications
- and many more...

All of these can be activated with a few simple lines of JSON.

If you don't need any of these features, and if you are instead looking to build a simpler static form with basic validations, then SurveyJS will probably be overkill for your needs.